# Striped table rows in ASP.NET MVC (without using jQuery or equivalent)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When using an ASP.NET WebForms [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) to display data in an HTML table I use the following technique in to "stripe" the table rows:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="<%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "alternate" %>">
        <!-- table cells in here -->
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

With the following CSS:

```
tr.alternate
{
    background-color: #EFF5FB;
}
```

I have just gone through the ASP.NET MVC [Movie Database Application tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx) and learnt that in MVC-land table rows can be (must be?) constructed as follows:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Title) %>
        </td>
        <!-- and so on for the rest of the table cells... -->
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

What can I add to this code to stripe the rows of my table?

Note: I know that this can be [done using jQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2006/10/18/zebra-table-showdown/), I want to know if it can be done another way.

### Edit

If jQuery (or equivalent) is in your opinion the best or most appropriate post, I'd be interested in knowing why.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another option that doesn't involve lambdas and is a bit cleaner than what you got working might be this...

```
<% int i=0; foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr class="<%= i++ % 2 == 0 ? "alternate" : "" %>">
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Title) %>
        </td>
        <!-- and so on for the rest of the table cells... -->
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the drive-by -1. The OP seemed uncomfortable with the extension method approach, he called his own solution clunky, so I suggested an option that doesn't use extension methods, and is less clunky. For this I get downvoted?

Comment: I for one, found your solution much simpler and perfectly suited to my own application.

Comment: I, too, liked your solution. +1 as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 7):

What about an extension method?

```
public static void Alternate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T, bool> action)
{
    bool state = false;
    foreach (T item in items)
        action(item, state = !state);
}
```

This way you could say:

```
<% movies.Alternate((movie, alt) => { %>
  <tr class="<%= alt ? "alternate" : "" %>">
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(movie.Title) %>
    </td>
    <!-- and so on for the rest of the table cells... -->
  </tr>
<% }); %>
```

Edit, additionally if you want the index, you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T, int> action)
{
    int state = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
        action(item, state++);
}
```

Comment: Wow - OK, but how do I get hold of the properties of each movie (item variable in the code of my post)?

(I updated my original question to show this)

Comment: Hi Richard, thats the first argument of the Action lambda, I called it movie in my example.. the part where it says: (movie, alt) are the argument names, the first argument 'movie' is the item, and alt is a boolean to indicate if this is an alternate row or not. You can change the parameter names.

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx if you've not used lambdas in c# before.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Alternating("alternate","") { %>
<tr class="<%= item.ClassName %>">
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Model.Title) %>
    </td>
    <!-- and so on for the rest of the table cells... -->
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Which uses this extension method:

```
 public class AlternatingItem<T> 
  {
   public string ClassName { get; set; }
   public T Model { get; set; }
  }
  public static IEnumerable<AlternatingItem<T>> Alternating<T>(this IEnumerable<T> model, string oddString, string evenString) 
  {
   int i = 0;
   var query = from x in model
      let c = i++ % 2 == 0 ? oddString : evenString
      select new AlternatingItem<T>() { ClassName = c, Model = x };
   return query;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Razor in for example .NET Core, this code works:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Stuff.Count; i++)
{
    <tr style="background: @(i % 2 == 0 ? "#f5f5f5" : string.Empty)">
        <td>
            @Model.Stuff[i].Name
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 